# Required type to be defined for useState in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

what is the required type to be defined for dataList in typescript
please refer below snippet

```
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]); 
      dataList= [
                 [{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}], 
                 [{header:"first",tail:"three"},{header:"second",tail:"four"}] 
                ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide the types for the `dataList` state, as TypeScript is unable to infer it. This can be done via interfaces or type alias.

```
interface Data {
  header: string;
  tail: string; 
}
```

And this is how you can use it on the `useState` generic parameter, whereby `dataList` is a multidimensional array of the `Data` interface that is defined above:

```
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState<Data[][]>([]);
```